# Parse JSON request without creating a class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In a Spring MVC controller method, I have a JSON input (request body) with just one field: `{"version":3}`. I can get this value like this:

```
@RequestMapping
public void myMethod(@RequestBody MyJsonRequest myJsonRequest) {

    int version = myJsonRequest.version;

    //...
}
```

But I have to create `MyJsonRequest` class with a `version` field. How can I get the `version` value without creating a new class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a map:

```
public void myMethod(@RequestBody Map<String, Integer> myJsonRequest) {

    int version = myJsonRequest.get("version");

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON data and then you can directly access to value of JSON response.

Consider data as myJsonRequest :

```
 var version=0;
 var jsonval = $.parseJSON(data);
 // you can use directly value of json data like 
 version = data.version;

 // If you returned an array in json response, then you can use $.each method and store value into single array, like this

 $.each(portals_array,function(i,v){
        version[] = v.version;

 });

alert(version);
};
```

It's working perfectly in my code. Check it out.

Comment: It is client side, he is asking to fetch the data on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it maps your json object to a primitive int variable:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/yourMapping", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void myMethod (@RequestBody int version) {

    //do something with your int variable version
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I try this code I get an exception with the message: `Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token`.

Comment: If I declare a `@RequestBody String version` parameter, I receive the entire JSON string in it: `{"version":3}`.

Comment: It's a RESTful web service. There is no client side code yet.

Comment: So, you do your request from browser I presume.

Comment: I do it from a desktop REST client (it's called RESTClient).

Comment: I see, when you type a client side code (I don't know if you will do it), for example java script, create a variable and assign the "version" object to a simple variable (var x and send it as a request), it will probably solve the problem.